# strptime string to datetime object conversion

Tags: python

I have a Python2.7 script with a variable `date= "21/05/2019"` that works fine. 
I need the `date` variable to be `datetime.now - 60 days`.

However the output must be like `time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=148, tm_isdst=-1)`

`datetime.datetime.now()` with `strptime` won't work.

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta

N = 60
#pre_create_date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=N)
pre_create_date = "28/04/2019"

# Sort out date format
pre_create_date = time.strptime(pre_create_date, "%d/%m/%Y")

print pre_create_date
```

I expect to be able to use `datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=N)` but the output to be a datetime object.

**Edit:**

It looks like I haven't explained myself very well. Sorry about that.

The script is:

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta

N = 60
#pre_create_date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=N)
pre_create_date = "28/04/2019"

# Sort out date format
pre_create_date = time.strptime(pre_create_date, "%d/%m/%Y")

print pre_create_date
```

Output:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=118, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Script using `datetime.now - datetime.timedelta`:

```
import datetime, time
from datetime import timedelta

N = 60
pre_create_date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=N)

print pre_create_date
```

Output:

```
2019-03-31 21:09:25.183459
```

Expected output:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=118, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: The output of `datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=N)` is `datetime.datetime` already. You don't need to use `strptime` on it. Am I missing something?

Comment: The output is a datetime object. You are just seeing the string representation of the object when you print it.

Comment: @HenryYik The output is not a `datetime` object. Rather it is a `time.struct_time` object. Notice, in the second last line we are calling `time.strptime()` rather then `datetime.strptime()` this results in a time object rather then a datetime object

Comment: I was referring to OP's last sentence regarding `datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=N)`.

Comment: The question is a little bit ambiguous, in the second paragraph OP states that he want the output format to be `time.struct_time()` which is of `time` object,  and in the last line, states that he wants a `datetime` object? Both lines are contradicting each other

Comment: I've just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:-**

```
import time
import datetime


print(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %w/%j"))

pre_create_date = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(60)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %w/%j")

print(pre_create_date)
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
2019-05-30 12:59:27 4/150
2019-03-31 12:59:27 0/090
```

**WORKING:-**

The above code first prints out the current Timestamp(the format is the one you asked for). And then outputs the 60 days early Timestamp from current date (today - 60).

Just used `strftime()` to get our desired attributes off the current date.

**EXPLANATION OF CODES USED IN `strftime()`:-**

```
%Y     Year with century as a decimal number.
%m     Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
%d     Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal.

%H     Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
%M     Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
%S     Second as a zero-padded decimal number.

%w     Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week). All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.
%j     Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

**NOTE:-** After passing the dates via `strftime()` the output will be of datatype `string`. If you want the output to be a datetime object then use:-

```
datetimeobj_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(pre_create_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %w/%j")
print(type(datetimeobj_1))
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

If you want the output to be a 'time.struct_time' object then use:-

```
datetimeobj_1 = time.strptime(pre_create_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %w/%j")
print(type(datetimeobj_1))
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
<class 'time.struct_time'>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks! `time.strptime(pre_create_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 1):

When using 
`pre_create_date = time.strptime(pre_create_date, "%d/%m/%Y")`

You are creating a `time.struct_time` object.

Use `datetime.datetime.strptime("28/04/2019", "%d/%m/%Y")` instead and I think you'll get what you aim for

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax problem, change `print pre_create_date` to `print (pre_create_date)` to start with and you are assigning a **string** to `pre_create_date` try to get it in date format, and use `pre_create_date = pre_create_date.strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f")` or any format as you you like,

good luck.